# How to download a webpage in php

Tags: php, parsing, html

I was wondering how I could download a webpage in php for parsing?

Answer (score 17):

You can use something like this

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a search website, just as a test. I'm trying to search another website using their search URL.

You type something into a search box and then it parses it through Google, for instance, and then displays the results from Google.

Answer (score 12):

Since you will likely want to parse the page with [DOM](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), you can load the page directly with:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('http://www.example.com');
```

when your PHP has [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled.

But basically, any function that supports [HTTP stream wrappers](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) can be used to download a page.

Comment: First line ought to be: 

$dom = new \DOMDocument();

Comment: @JasonGabler Unless you defined your own DOMDocument class in your namespace, PHP will fallback to the global namespace prefix. So it's optional to add. Backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 8):

With the [curl](http://php.net/curl) library.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add another option because it is there, while not the best is just to use file. Its another option that I dont see anyone has listed here.

```
$array = file("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

Its nice if you want it in an array of lines, whereas the already mentioned file_get_contents will put it in a string.

Just another thing you can do.

Then you can loop thru each line if this matches your goal to do so:

```
foreach($array as $line){

    echo $line;
    // do other stuff here

}
```

This comes in handy sometimes when certain APIs spit out plain text or html with a new entry on each line.

Comment: this is worked for me and read javascripts and also json in it

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code

```
$url = 'your url';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
// you can do something with $data like explode(); or a preg match regex to get the exact information you need
//$data = strip_tags($data);
echo $data;
```